# snmp traps are getting missed even generating in the same machine

Tags: snmp, rhel6

Why snmp traps that are generating from the same machines are getting missed in RHEL6.5 ?
What could be the problem ?

Same code is ran on RHEL5.5 traps are not getting missed.

Comment: Is this a programming question? Reads more like networking or systems administration to me, in which case it should rather be posted on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

I think that firewall is cause of this behaviour. Try to `service iptables stop` and `service iptables6 stop`